# Relative path from unmanaged delphi DLL raises an exception

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have a Delphi DLL with exported functions. I want a relative path in my `dllimport` statement with that DLL where the executable for the Windows Forms can be found. However, I receive this exception:

> Additional information: Unable to find an entry point name.

```
public class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("DelphiDll.dll",
               EntryPoint = "InitDll",
               CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    ...
```

When I put the absolute path it works without a problem. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Because you specified just the DLL name without its path, the system DLL search path is used to locate the DLL. That is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx

Since the error is *entry-point not found* that indicates that a DLL has been found, but it does not export that function. You also report that with an absolute path, the entry point is found. From that evidence we can conclude that there are multiple versions of this DLL on your machine.

The best place to put the DLL is in the same directory as the executable. That is the first placed searched. Put the correct version of the DLL there.

Comment: I put the zip with the executable and the dll file that is imported in the executable on virtual machine. (clean slate). App failed i believe it just couldn't find the dll. Perhaps , setdlldirectory could help

Comment: Don't try stuff at random. You don't need SetDllDirectory if everything is in the same directory. Entry point not found means the dll loads but doesn't have that function. Clean machine could be missing other dependencies.

Comment: it is just that on my local machine, i placed the dll where my executable is. Even if i have this same dll placed in other folders can it still issue this exception of not being able to find the entry?

Comment: Use a tool like Process Monitor to learn where the DLL is being loaded from. If the DLL really is with the executable, that's the first search location. But maybe there are onward dependencies. Perhaps you need to simplify as a way to learn.